# How to read a PDF,Word and Excel files from LinkButton click ? + Asp.Net + C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to read a `PDF` ,`Word` and `Excel` files from LinkButton click ? + `Asp.Net`+ `C#`.

This is my code :

```
protected void LinkButton155_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.msword"; 
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\suppression des doublons.docx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.WriteFile("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\suppression des doublons.docx");


}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

For Excel Files:

```
protected void LinkButton153_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\decret.xlsx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.WriteFile("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\decret.xlsx");       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDF Files :

```
protected void LinkButton154_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Acces_aux_marches.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Accès aux marchés/Acces_aux_marches.pdf"));
    Response.End();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void LinkButton155_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.msword"; 
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\decret.docx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.WriteFile("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\decret.docx");
}
```